# What is the best way to make your text stay in the same line as your icons?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this UI here

[image]

---

I've tried

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

#cb-key-danger{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #F46E4E;
}

#cb-key-warning{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #F9C262 ;
}

#cb-key-success{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #ADB55E;
}

.cb-key-row{
  background-color: #E2E2E2 ;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.cb-key-row span {
 display: inline;
}



</style>
```

---

### HTML

```
<div class="row cb-key-row ">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div id="cb-key-danger" ></div>
    <span> &lt; 50% CLASS AVERAGE SCORE </span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div id="cb-key-warning" ></div>
    <span> 50% UP TO 75% CLASS AVERAGE SCORE </span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div id="cb-key-success" ></div>
    <span> &gt; OR EQUAL TO 75% CLASS AVERAGE SCORE </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Result

[image]

How can I make my texts stay next to my icons ?

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/urzr4pgj/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `display: inline-block` for squares divs:

```
#cb-key-danger{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #F46E4E;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cb-key-warning{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #F9C262;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cb-key-success{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #ADB55E;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cb-key-row{
  background-color: #E2E2E2 ;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.cb-key-row span {
 display: inline;
}
```

Comment: it has to be inline-block, since there are width and height defined.

Comment: @Pangloss Oh! Yes. Inline elements can not have width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

## 1 display: inline-block;

Your container behaviour like chars (ex. span)
You can fix position with with line-height.

```
#cb-key-danger {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #F46E4E;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or set margin-left for your span and:
set background icon / set postion absolute

Examples http://jsfiddle.net/kgk2yrs9/1/

Comment: absolute positioning is bad idea.